# Unity не может подключиться

Tags: unity3d

2 дня назад начались проблемы, юнити сначала не хотел заходить в ассет стор, потом починился, но перестал работать коллаб (выдает что-то вроде "Can't get revision from server"), а так же при билде зависал на построении первой сцены. Хотел проверить обновление, но там тоже не может подключиться (версия 2017.1.1f1)., При этом спокойной коннектится к ассет стору. Удалил, скачал последнюю версию с сайта, предварительно подчистив все файлы со старой, но проблема осталась! Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Это последствия блокировок роскомнадзора. Ставьте VPN

Comment: Пришел к другу (с которым был коллаб) проверить, удалили проект, сказали из облака, сделали пару изменений иивсетрабоьало отлично...

Answer (score 0):

Есть 3 варианта.
1. Блокировка служб Unity Collaboration.
2. Смена версии проекта.
3. Проблемы с интернет подключением или FireWall.
На время блокировки можно использовать GitHub.